Solving differential equation through function
Folks! I am trying to obtain the plot the phase portrait of the following differential equation in Mathematica. My task is to do the work through function by numerical solution. The equation is:
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\alpha \frac{d\theta}{dt}+\omega_o^2\sin\theta=f \cos(\omega t).$$
My written approach: I first try to define the function that numerically evaluates the solution in the same phase plot function:
phaseplot[f_,\[Alpha]_,w_,Subscript[w,o]_,i1_,i2_]:=ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{\[Theta][t],\[Theta]'[t]}/.NDSolve[{\[Theta]''[t]+\[Alpha] \[Theta]'[t]+Subscript[w, o]^2 Sin[\[Theta][t]]==f Cos[w*t],\[Theta][0]==i1,\[Theta]'[0]==i2},\[Theta],{t,0,10}][[1]]],{t,0,10}]

This should give me an output, I am unable to find the error. My phase plot function takes an all the constants(f,$\alpha$) as the argument along with the initial conditions(i1,i2) and at the same time solves the equation.
My another failed approach:
sol[f_,\[alpha]_,w_,Subscript[w,o]_,i1_,i2_]:=NDSolve[{\[Theta]''[t]+\[Alpha] \[Theta]'[t]+Subscript[w, o]^2 Sin[\[Theta][t]]==f Cos[w*t],\[Theta][0]==i1,\[Theta]'[0]==i2},\[Theta],{t,0,10}]
phaseplot[sol_]:=ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{\[Theta][t],\[Theta]'[t]}/.sol[[1]]],{t,0,10}]


What do you mean "failed"? What output did you actually get? Did it throw any errors? This is all relevant info that you should provide in your post. In addition, please provide reasonable values for the parameters so that we don't have to guess  what they should be. Finally *do not use Subscripts in code. They don't work how you think they should work. Here, Subscript[w,o]_ is interpreted as ``Subscript[w,o]*times* something else, which is likely not what you meant. Usewo` or something like that instead.

Your code needs just a small modification phaseplot[f_, \[Alpha]_, w_, i1_, i2_] :=   ParametricPlot[   Evaluate[{\[Theta][t], \[Theta]'[t]} /.      NDSolve[{\[Theta]''[t] + \[Alpha] \[Theta]'[t] +           w Sin[\[Theta][t]] == f Cos[w*t], \[Theta][0] ==          i1, \[Theta]'[0] == i2}, \[Theta], {t, 0, 10}][[1]]], {t, 0,     10}] and phaseplot[4, 1, 2, 0, 0]

You can use ParametricNDSolve, e.g.
func = {y[t], y'[t]} /. 
   ParametricNDSolve[{y''[t] + a y'[t] + w^2 Sin[y[t]] == f Cos[p t], 
     y[0] == i1, y'[0] == i2}, {y[t], y'[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, {a, w, f, p,
      i1, i2}];
phase[a_, w_, f_, p_, i1_, i2_, u_] := 
 Table[func[[j]][a, w, f, p, i1, i2] /. t -> u, {j, 2}]

Using the same parameters as @Nasser:
ParametricPlot[phase[1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0, t], {t, 0, 5}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {\[Theta], \[Theta]'}]



good you used ParametricNDSolve as I was too lazy to add it myself as another way to do this.

You could do
ode = y''[t] + a*y'[t] + w0^2*Sin[y[t]] == f*Cos[w*t];
ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
params = {a -> 1, w0 -> 2, w -> 3, f -> 4};
maxTime = 5;
sol = NDSolveValue[{ode /. params, ic}, {y, y'}, {t, 0, maxTime}] ;
ParametricPlot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, maxTime}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"y(t)", "y'(t)"}, BaseStyle -> 14, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 AspectRatio -> Full]


You could make it as a function or use Manipulate and make sliders for the parameters which would be better.
Another option is to use ParametricNDSolve.
